# UUID mapping with JPA only

Tags: java, jpa

I have an application using UUID like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "query_indicator")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public final class QueryIndicatorEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  @Column(name = "uuid", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
  private UUID uuid;
....
}
```

Is there a way to replace the @Type hibernate annotation by full JPA in order to be be completly independant from the choosen ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I've converted in data base my uuids char to binary 16.
So I've just this mapping

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID uuid;
```

No more necessary to have hibernate (5) annotation

```
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
```

Here is a sample MySql Server script to migrate column from char to binary

```
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY COLUMN uuid VARBINARY(36) NOT NULL;
UPDATE sample set uuid=UUID_TO_BIN(UUID());
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY COLUMN uuid BINARY(16) NOT NULL;
```